Why is this if written like this?
I was reading the code for the hci_qcomm_init tool from Qualcomm and I have noticed this if that is written in a way I've never seen before:
if (bt_hci_qcomm_pfal_get_bdaddress((uint8*)(&run_time_params.bd_address[0])) == TRUE)
{
}
else
{
    DEBUGMSG(ZONE_WARNING,TEXT("bt_hci_qcomm_init Failed to read BD Address from NV default to %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X"),
        (int)default_bt_bd_addr[0],(int)default_bt_bd_addr[1],(int)default_bt_bd_addr[2],
        (int)default_bt_bd_addr[3],(int)default_bt_bd_addr[4],(int)default_bt_bd_addr[5]  );

    // using default BT address
    std_memmove((uint8*)(&run_time_params.bd_address[0]), (const uint8 *)(&(default_bt_bd_addr[0])),BT_QSOC_MAX_BD_ADDRESS_SIZE);
}

Is there any reason why you would write an if with the if part empty and all the action in the else or did they just make a mistake there?
I would have personally compared the result from the function to FALSE (or add a ! before the function) and avoid using the else.

No special reason, maybe for readability, in order to emphasize the fact that if the result is TRUE we want to do nothing. The generated code would most likely be the same regardless of the way the condition is written and the fact that an empty statement and an else is used or not.

Might be the result of removing statements from the positive side, and not wanting to disrupt the structure seen in diff.  And the safe change when removing {} else would be to replace == with != - anything else is risky without knowing how TRUE is defined and what values the function may return...

I'd probably add a comment inside the otherwise empty block saying // Address retrieved OK, nothing to do here or similar so it's more obvious.

Since that code fragment does not conform to kernel coding style, it probably was never reviewed by the kernel developers of the mailing list.


Why is this if written like this?

There is insufficient information in the question to definitively determine what was in the author’s mind. Possibilities include:

The author wished to write if ( test)… else… statements in which test is naturally “true” or affirmative, rather than using a negation, because they believed it was better for human readability and understanding.
The author wished to write code in which all “then” portions of if statements handled normal working conditions and the “else” portions handled errors, and this particular if… else… statement did not need any further code for the normal case, so that case is empty.
The program originally had code in the “then” case, but it was eliminated by subsequent revisions to the program, and the programmer making those revisions decided to do the minimal amount of work of removing the no-longer-needed code without doing additional work of rewriting the if… else… statement to be only an if… statement.
The code was generated by automatic code-writing software from other input, and that generation result in an empty “then” case.

